# Prepared Statement is very slow compared to direct statement

Tags: sql-server, jmeter, prepared-statement

I'm doing load testing on a SQL Server Database. The table that I'm testing contains roughly 800 million records. I'm using Jmeter JDBC request to perform the testing.

I'm running a query similar to below:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table_name where table_key='32CharString'
```

Here `table_key` is the primary key on the table and it is of length `varchar(32)`.

In Jmeter JDBC request, if I hardcode the table_key, then the query runs in **~170 milliseconds**.

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table_name
where table_key='1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef';
```

Instead if I pass it as a parameter to a the same query using prepared statement, the query executes successfully in about **900+ seconds**.

`select column1, column2, column3, column4 from table_name where table_key=?`

`Parameter` = 1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef
`Type`= varchar

I'm not able to figure out how there is this much time difference in query execution. Please provide some pointers

Comment: basically, you have to compare the execution plans. Without this information, I can only recommend you to read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx

Comment: At the very minimum, include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) in your question. You did post the query and the parameter, but it's not the complete code fragment. To answer this correctly provide all relevant context, in this case the code fragment with the `PreparedStatement`. You can provide this by clicking `edit` underneath your question then paste the code in your question. Then select that code and click the `{}` button to format the code properly.

Comment: There are some cases where different parameter values can result in a different optimization plan. Then that optimization plan is cached, and used the next time you execute the query with different parameter values. But the optimization plan isn't the best plan for the changed query. So you need to compare your execution plans and optimize the executing. For the beginning include the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, more about parameter sniffing https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: I'd recommend to read a very good article by Erland Sommarskog: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) He explains in detail what is parameter sniffing that @krtek mentioned above, how to deal with it and other related areas.

Answer (score 0):

"Parameter = 1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef Type= varchar" seems suspicious to me. Specifically, "`varchar(<missing length here>)`". My theory is that it's being parameterized as a wider varchar type (say `varchar(300)`) and SQL Server is doing the following "`select <col list> from table_name where cast(table_key as varchar(300)) = ?`". Which for SQL Server means that it has to touch every row in your table.

To confirm my theory, you can look at the execution plans for your ad hoc and your prepared statements. If I'm right, you should see a seek in your ad hoc plan and a scan in the prepared statement. Moreover, I think you'll also see a compute scalar operation in your prepared statement for the upconversion to whatever datatype the statement preparation is choosing.